How to get the current Android store version in .net maui
How would I go about getting the current Android store version for the Google Play Store?
It looks like we have to pull in the entire page and then parse the version out of that HTML, but I haven't found any way that works at the moment.
Does anyone have a working way in .net maui?

There is no way other than parsing the store page, or by hosting your own page/service that returns the current release version.

What do you need this for? May be the problem you're trying to solve can be dealt with in a different way.
